# EKS - Multiple certificates to one ingress-nginx

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

There are some applications deployed in the `EKS` Cluster and I am trying to manage custom domains (DNS) with `Route53`, `Certificate Manager` (HTTPS). I have deployed `ingress-nginx` to map the dns and path to the correct pod.

Basically, there are some clients/pods that are using custom domain, and other clients with the company domain, for example:

- https://clientA **.mycompany.com**
- https://clientB **.mycompany.com**
- https://clientW **customdomain.com**

As we can see in the following diagram, to fix the 1 service to 1 certificate (1:1) we need to create an ingress-proxy group by domain (.mycompany.com and customdomain.com).

[image]

**What's the problem?** That custom domain is different per client (Examples: carsAcompany.com, fridgesBcompany.com...) so we need to create ingress-nginx per each one except for *.mycompany.com and I think that's not a good practise.

The think is... I am using ingress-nginx (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) provided by Kubernetes, but, Is there an alternative plugin / ingress that allows multiple certificates to the same service? Or the same ingress-nginx is able to use multiple certificates?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use? I have found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53704915/how-can-i-add-multiple-certificates-to-ingress-for-the-same-ip-with-sub-domain). Is it helpful?

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem and the way I solved it is not pretty but it definitely worked for me and am happy with it.

In our firm, we were using Vault for secret management but we're using ACM for certs. As we know that nginx ingress controller only supports having 1 ACM cert configured on it. So, Instead of using ACM certificates on the ingress controller service, I created created certs using Vault (Vault can act as it's own CA).

Now I export those certs into k8s as secrets and defined them on the ingress resource for each application. So, this way, I get to have a unique cert for each application using nginx ingress controller.

Comment: Thanks @YYashwanth for your reply. Are you using Vault as CA also? Because I was using certificates created in ACM as AWS as the CA.

Comment: @user1911 Yep. I am using Vault as a CA. Using ACM as the CA works as long as we can export the certificates. I think we can export the certificates if we have a private CA.